# GCP GKE node pool auto schedule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

i'm pretty new in GCP and wonder how can I schedule my GKE cluster node pool that contain 3 GPU machines.
I found that the operating cost of these machines is very high so I was looking for a solution that could automatically turn off all these machines/pool every night and turn them on every morning as this is a development project.

Comment: You can use a cron job and deploy a cloud function, send a signal (http endpoint / pubsub message) to it. In your cloud function, you can start/shutdown your compute engine via the client library sdk or http RESTful api

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to create two nodes pools:

```
-<default-node-pool> for kube-system pods
-<gpu-node-pool>
```

The reason why having only one node pool will not work is because a node pool will not scale down to 0, somehow kube-sytem pods need to live somewhere.

You may use the concept of [node taint](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints#creating_a_node_pool_with_node_taints) in order to create  your gpu node pool with this flag

> --node-taints cost=high:NoSchedule

Then you can apply toleration to pods as below

```
tolerations:
- key: cost
operator: Equal
value: high
effect: NoSchedule
```

In that way you are making sure that your kube-system pods are not being scheduled on the GPU nodes. There will be some kube-system pods that will run on the nodepool regardless because they have a toleration for everything.

With autoscaler on, and if a [node is not needed](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-does-scale-down-work), gpu node pool should scale down to 0 while keeping default node pool alive for kube-system pods.